# The variable value does not change when using a dynamic URL in Flutter 3 webview

Tags: flutter, webview, uri, flutter-3.10

I've created a Flutter 3 webview page with a dynamic URL. The URL contains several parameters that I store in shared preferences. The issue is that these parameters aren't being filled when the URL is loaded. My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:antrian/config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeTab({super.key});
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var urlfull;
  var authUserId = '';
  var username = '';
  var token = '';
  var pegawaiId = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    startLaunching();
    super.initState();
    //untuk melakukan refresh tampilan
  }

  startLaunching() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      authUserId = prefs.getString("auth_user_id")!;
      username = prefs.getString("username")!;
      token = prefs.getString("token")!;
      pegawaiId = prefs.getString("pegawai_id")!;
      urlfull = "index?q=$authUserId&u=$username&t=$token&p=$pegawaiId";
    });
  }

  late WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onProgress: (int progress) {},
      onPageStarted: (String url) {},
      onPageFinished: (String url) {},
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
    ))
    ..enableZoom(false)
    // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(baseUrlMobile + urlfull));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
        ));
  }
}
```

The expected URL should be like this:
https://example.com/index?q=1111&u=222&t=333&p=444
but what is being generated is:
https://example.com/index?q=&u=&t=&p=

Comment: Although you initialize urlfull in startLaunching(), the code that initializes the WebViewController will actually get run first.  You should probably initialize the controller variable after initializing urlfull.